# Highly correlated but weak instrument?

Tags: instrumental-variables

I have an instrument and an endogenous variable that correlated at a level of 0.42. This seems to me to be sufficiently strong, but whenever I perform any Wald statistics or weak instrument tests, the results show that there is a weak instrument with very low F scores. How can this be?

Comment: .42 is not exactly what's generally understood as highly correlated.